# Server-Client 2player Game in Java

Tags: java, serversocket

I am a new one in Java programming i want to know how overall concept of Socket and Server-Client work and how modification in one's system tends to the modification in other's system, As a starter i am making TicTacToe 2 player in java, i had made TicTacToe for Single Player but want some help to make it in multiplayer.I had gone through many question (on this site) before but they only solve some kind of problem but i want a full knowledge that how this all stuff works.
Can any one please tell me that how Server and Client do the message passing in Java ??

I want to ask where to write my Game Code so that it get loaded on both the devices and when user make a turn it get displayed into another user's device also...

Comment: What you are asking is a really broad area. Java Client Server communication can be done several ways like Socket, RMI and many more third party APIs. Teaching those is not possible in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different answers/solutions for the use-case you described.

But **never never** develop network communication on a low-level layer. There are different solutions (api) to put the data(messages) into higher layers(f.e. HTTP). That enables you to turn your software very easy into a multithreaded and/or multisession-app.

I would prefer in your simple application an implementation with jersey and grizzly. You'll find lot of how-to's with google ("web services jersey grizzly") and here in stackoverflow of course. ;)